# pidstat says the task kB_wr/s is not zero, but I can't find who write use strace

Tags: io, linux-kernel, strace, etcd

I use this command `pidstat -p 30716 -d -r  1 10` to check process 30716 is doing I/O. The command output like following:

```
Average:      UID       PID  minflt/s  majflt/s     VSZ    RSS   %MEM  Command
Average:        0     30716      0.00      0.00 4938144 256296   3.20  etcd_refresher

Average:      UID       PID   kB_rd/s   kB_wr/s kB_ccwr/s  Command
Average:        0     30716      0.00      1.20      0.00  etcd_refresher
```

But I can't find who is doing I/O use strace, the strace is as following:

```
futex(0x7fa4240034f4, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x7fa4240034f0, FUTEX_OP_SET<<28|0<<12|FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT<<24|0x1) = 1
futex(0x7fa46c004004, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7fa46c003fd8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
sendmsg(80, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\0\0\21\1\4\0\0@A\312\311\310\277\306\305\304\303\302\0172\00512", iov_len=23}, {iov_base="10m\0\0\4\10\0\0\0@A\0\0\0\5\0\0\377\0\1\0\0", iov_len=23}, {iov_base="@A\0\0\0\0\372", iov_len=7}, {iov_base="\nR\20\3\32\35service/00000001/runtime_u"..., iov_len=250}, {iov_base="\0\0\4\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0/", iov_len=13}], msg_iovlen=5, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 316
futex(0x7fa4240034f4, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x7fa4240034f0, FUTEX_OP_SET<<28|0<<12|FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT<<24|0x1) = 1
futex(0x7fa46c004214, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7fa46c0041e8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
nanosleep({tv_sec=1, tv_nsec=200000000}, NULL) = 0
sendmsg(80, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\0\0\21\1\4\0\0@C\312\311\310\300\306\305\304\303\302\0172\00512", iov_len=23}, {iov_base="10m\0\0\4\10\0\0\0@C\0\0\0\5\0\0\7\0\1\0\0", iov_len=23}, {iov_base="@C\0\0\0\0\2\10\36\0\0\4\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\7\0", iov_len=23}, {iov_base="\0\10\6\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\2\t", iov_len=16}], msg_iovlen=4, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 85
futex(0x7fa4240034f4, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x7fa4240034f0, FUTEX_OP_SET<<28|0<<12|FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT<<24|0x1) = 1
futex(0x7fa46c004004, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7fa46c003fd8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
sendmsg(80, {msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\0\0\21\1\4\0\0@E\312\311\310\277\306\305\304\303\302\0172\00512", iov_len=23}, {iov_base="10m\0\0\4\10\0\0\0@E\0\0\0\5\0\0\377\0\1\0\0", iov_len=23}, {iov_base="@E\0\0\0\0\372", iov_len=7}, {iov_base="\nR\20\3\32\35service/00000001/runtime_u"..., iov_len=250}, {iov_base="\0\0\4\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0/", iov_len=13}], msg_iovlen=5, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 316
futex(0x7fa4240034f4, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x7fa4240034f0, FUTEX_OP_SET<<28|0<<12|FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT<<24|0x1) = 1
futex(0x7fa46c004214, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL) = 0
futex(0x7fa46c0041e8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
```

So as you can see, the above is not related to I/O. So How can I find who is doing I/O in process 30716.
Note: process 30716 is just a etcd-client, and it access etcd-server each seconds, then sleep 1 second.
Thank you for read this question.

Comment: `sendmsg` is I/O (specifically, O).

Comment: I test command "ping www.google.com", and strace display functions: 1. sendto 2. recvmsg 3.write 4.poll.  The function sendto like function sendmsg, but the command ```watch -n 1 cat /proc/10140/io``` output write_bytes is always zero. So I think sendmsg is not I/O.